# How to add .lnk file in perforce

Tags: perforce

I am trying to checkin my source code into perforce but the docs folder containing the .lnk file to actual documents (in other folders) is not being uploaded.
Is there a way to checkin the .lnk file into perforce ?

Comment: It's not clear why you want to do that.  What do you mean by ".lnk file to actual documents (in other folders)"?  Is the `.lnk` file pointing to a file (or folder) on your local file system?  If so, how do you expect that to work for other people?

Comment: @jamesdlin I have lot of document file spread across multiple folders and just wan the shortcuts to them in single doc folder. So when I checkin this folder, it doesn't seems to recognize the .lnk files .

Comment: Again: how do you expect that to work for other people?  Or are you the only user of the Perforce repository? (`.lnk` files are capable of storing relative paths, but you need special tools to create such files.)

Comment: Also, I just tried doing `p4 add SOME_SHORTCUT.lnk` followed by `p4 submit`, and it worked fine.  Please provide exact details about what you're doing and about what happens.

Comment: (_Also, I just tried doing `p4 add SOME_SHORTCUT.lnk`..._)

This is a good insight! The P4V client wouldn't let me drag the Windows shortcut onto a changelist to open it for add (which works for other kinds of files), but using `p4 add` did the trick. Cheers!